# elseif in wordpress template

Tags: wordpress, if-statement

how can I add some echo to render a paragraf if there is no posts?

```
            <?php query_posts('cat=1'.get_the_title().'&post_status=publish,future');?>
            <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <div class="thumb"><?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?></div>                  
            <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
            <p><?php $content = get_the_content();
            echo substr($content, 0, 20000); ?>...
            <span class="more"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">czytaj więcej...</a></span>
            </p>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can put `else` after the `while` loop:

```
        <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php else: ?>    

    <p> no posts found</p> 

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php query_posts('cat=1'.get_the_title().'&post_status=publish,future');?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="thumb"><?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?></div>                  
    <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
    <p><?php $content = get_the_content();
    echo substr($content, 0, 20000); ?>...
    <span class="more"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">czytaj więcej...</a></span>
    </p>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else : ?>
    <!-- Content to show when there are no posts. -->
<?php endif; ?>
```